# ошибка при инициализации с помощью std::tie

Tags: c++

Ошибка при инициализации с помощью `std::tie`

```
sf::Texture const& texture();
std::map<EnemyAction, unsigned> amountFrame;
std::map<EnemyAction, sf::IntRect> enemyRect;
float damage;
std::tie(texture, enemyRect, amountFrame, damage) = (enemy.type == "small_zombie") ? 
    std::make_tuple(m_gameTexture.GetEnemyTexture(), smallEnemyRect, smallEnemyFrame, SMALL_ZOMBIE_DAMAGE)
    : std::make_tuple(m_gameTexture.GetBigEnemyTexture(), bigEnemyRect, bigEnemyFrame, BIG_ZOMBIE_DAMAGE);
```

Ошибка

```
note: см. ссылку на создание экземпляров функции шаблон при компиляции 
"std::tuple<const sf::Texture &(__cdecl &)(void),std::map<EnemyAction,sf::IntRect,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> &,std::map<_Kty,unsigned int,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,unsigned int>>> &,float &> &std::tuple<const sf::Texture &(__cdecl &)(void),std::map<_Kty,_Ty,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> &,std::map<_Kty,unsigned int,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,unsigned int>>> &,float &>::operator =<sf::Texture,std::map<_Kty,_Ty,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>,std::map<_Kty,unsigned int,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,unsigned int>>>,float>(std::tuple<sf::Texture,std::map<_Kty,_Ty,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>,std::map<_Kty,unsigned int,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,unsigned int>>>,float> &&)"
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=EnemyAction,
1>              _Ty=sf::IntRect
1>          ]
1>  Game.cpp(62): note: см. ссылку на создание экземпляров функции шаблон при компиляции "std::tuple<const sf::Texture &(__cdecl &)(void),std::map<EnemyAction,sf::IntRect,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> &,std::map<_Kty,unsigned int,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,unsigned int>>> &,float &> &std::tuple<const sf::Texture &(__cdecl &)(void),std::map<_Kty,_Ty,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> &,std::map<_Kty,unsigned int,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,unsigned int>>> &,float &>::operator =<sf::Texture,std::map<_Kty,_Ty,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>,std::map<_Kty,unsigned int,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,unsigned int>>>,float>(std::tuple<sf::Texture,std::map<_Kty,_Ty,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>,std::map<_Kty,unsigned int,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,unsigned int>>>,float> &&)"
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=EnemyAction,
1>              _Ty=sf::IntRect
1>          ]
```

Answer (score 2):

`sf::Texture const& texture();` это объявление функции, а не переменной.